# SDL Tridion 2013 Legacy pack

Tags: 2013

1. What extra's are installed when installing SDL Tridion 2013 with legacy pack, compared to SDL Tridion 2013 without legacy pack.
2. And if installed with lecagy pack on development server do I have to install the legacy pack on the test and production server also?

Answer (score 8):

Legacy feature contains:

- Script templates
- VB6 event system

Not part of the legacy feature, but is not selected by default is Business Connector.
If you are going to use any of these features - you need to install it both on production and test system.

Answer (score 4):

I created a blog post with a bit of information that should answer your question here:

http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/sdl-tridion-2013-whats-new

If you're after greater detail, the post also contains a link to a video where SDL talks about the legacy pack.